# TX fails in private blockchain when trying to access an ERC20 contract from another contract

Tags: erc-20, private-blockchain, out-of-gas

I have an ERC20 contract and I am trying to access it from another contract, which is a Faucet. In the Faucet I have a function to query an account's balance, and another one to transfer some tokens to an account.

When I test everything in Ganache or Ropsten, it works normally. When I test this in a private local Geth network, this happens:

- I am able to deploy both contracts.
- I am able to transfer some tokens from the ERC20 to the Faucet.
- When I try to query the balance of an account by sending a transaction to the Faucet I get: "Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?"
- When I try to do a transfer by calling the Faucet, the transaction fails (it is mined, I get a transaction hash, but it fails and consumes all the gas).

What could I be missing? This doesn't seem like a problem in the contracts.

This is the Faucet's code:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;

import "./Token/ERC20Basic.sol";
import "./Token/SafeERC20.sol";

contract Faucet {
    event AccountFunded(address account);

    address public tokenAddress;

    constructor(address _tokenAddress) public payable {
        tokenAddress = _tokenAddress;
    }

    function () external payable {}

    function testBalance(address account) public view returns (uint) {
        return ERC20Basic(tokenAddress).balanceOf(account);
    }

    function transfer(address account) public {
        SafeERC20.safeTransfer(ERC20Basic(tokenAddress), account, 10);
        emit AccountFunded(account);
    }
}
```

I am deploying and calling the contracts with Truffle. I tried different gas limits for the private geth network. This is the genesis file:

```
{
  "config": {
        "chainId": 1337,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
  "alloc"      : {},
  "coinbase"   : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "difficulty" : "0x100",
  "extraData"  : "",
  "gasLimit"   : "0x700000000",
  "nonce"      : "0x0000000000000042",
  "mixhash"    : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp"  : "0x00"
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using solc v0.5? Since solc v0.5 uses new constantinople & petersburg opcodes perhaps the issue is that your private blockchain doesn't have them enabled. That should generate invalid opcode error message and consume all gas available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't know if ERC20Basic uses the `require` opcode or some other opcode that was introduced later in development, I would try changing your `genesis.json`'s `"config"` object to look something like this:

```
"homesteadBlock": 0,
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip150Block": 0,
"eip160Block": 0,
"eip158Block": 0,
"byzantiumBlock": 0,
"constantinopleBlock": 0,
"petersburgBlock": 0
```

It is most probably an issue with `byzantiumBlock` not being set.

Edit: Taking Ismael's point into account, I've added `constantinopleBlock` and `petersburgBlock` to config.

Comment: Just posted a question related to this as now I am unable to apply these changes to the genesis file of a Parity node that was connected to my Geth client: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/70765/parity-2-2-7-doesnt-recognize-registrar-or-eip150transition-in-the-genesis