# Error: gas required exceeds allowance (8000000) or always failing transaction

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain

I deployed a test ERC20 to a private ethereum blockchain. It deployed fine because I can get the transaction receipt, see the logs and everything looks ok as far as I can tell. However, when I try to read the name or the symbol, I get this error. Why would reading the name of the contract even complain about gas? Same error for reading symbol or decimal. The smart contract deployed locally is the erc20.sol shown here - https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/30/writing-an-erc20-token-contract/

Also, name and symbol are public, so anybody should be able to read them right?

```
> eth.getTransactionReceipt('0x2b7dcfb8ab3a9f2a43c58d3bbd6031fb450968f767dfc83148eb6dff7cdc636d')
{
  blockHash: "0x24375675619d17e72bcbff2840b0235111674e36986c1801614047d38274ee23",
  blockNumber: 5364,
  contractAddress: "0x53bb83974e6db225449a1bde977a4b713e5560c1",
  cumulativeGasUsed: 906745,
  from: "0xacaebcdd3ca568a168a7f77052b7f0ccd7c23d19",
  gasUsed: 906745,
  logs: [{
      address: "0x53bb83974e6db225449a1bde977a4b713e5560c1",
      blockHash: "0x24375675619d17e72bcbff2840b0235111674e36986c1801614047d38274ee23",
      blockNumber: 5364,
      data: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d3c21bcecceda1000000",
      logIndex: 0,
      removed: false,
      topics: ["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef", "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "0x000000000000000000000000acaebcdd3ca568a168a7f77052b7f0ccd7c23d19"],
      transactionHash: "0x2b7dcfb8ab3a9f2a43c58d3bbd6031fb450968f767dfc83148eb6dff7cdc636d",
      transactionIndex: 0
  }],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000800000000000000000000000090000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000",
  root: "0x5a9d6b4abcdced377c72f9915175bf69062f4b5ce2381497976228eebc4637c7",
  to: null,
  transactionHash: "0x2b7dcfb8ab3a9f2a43c58d3bbd6031fb450968f767dfc83148eb6dff7cdc636d",
  transactionIndex: 0
}

> erc20.name()
Error: gas required exceeds allowance (8000000) or always failing transaction
    at web3.js:3143:20
    at web3.js:6347:15
    at web3.js:5081:36
    at web3.js:4137:16
    at apply (<native code>)
    at web3.js:4223:16
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

PS: erc20 above is obtained as follows:

```
> abi = [{"inputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"success","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"","type":"uint8"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"success","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"success","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]

> interface = eth.contract(abi)

> erc20 = interface.at('0x53BB83974E6dB225449a1Bde977a4B713e5560c1')
```

The solidity contract from https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/30/writing-an-erc20-token-contract/ is slightly modified pragma to suit the installed version of solidity

```
pragma solidity > 0.5.7 < 0.6.2;

contract SimpleERC20Token {
    // Track how many tokens are owned by each address.
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    // Modify this section
    string public name = "Simple ERC20 Token";
    string public symbol = "SET";
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    uint256 public totalSupply = 1000000 * (uint256(10) ** decimals);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    constructor() public {
        // Initially assign all tokens to the contract's creator.
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, totalSupply);
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= value);

        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= value;  // deduct from sender's balance
        balanceOf[to] += value;          // add to recipient's balance
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }

    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);

    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

    function approve(address spender, uint256 value)
        public
        returns (bool success)
    {
        allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value)
        public
        returns (bool success)
    {
        require(value <= balanceOf[from]);
        require(value <= allowance[from][msg.sender]);

        balanceOf[from] -= value;
        balanceOf[to] += value;
        allowance[from][msg.sender] -= value;
        emit Transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Genesys file for the private network

```
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 15,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip150Block": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "difficulty": "100",
    "gasLimit": "2100000",
    "alloc": {
        "7df9a875a174b3bc565e6424a0050ebc1b2d1d82": { "balance": "300000" },
        "f41c74c9ae680c1aa78f42e5647a62f353b7bdde": { "balance": "400000" }
    }
}
```

Comment: which web3.js version are you using?

Comment: Geth console, > web3.version shows {
  api: "0.20.1",
  ethereum: "0x40",
  network: "15",
  node: "Geth/v1.9.10-unstable-3bb6815f-20191224/darwin-amd64/go1.13",
  whisper: undefined,
  getEthereum: function(callback),
  getNetwork: function(callback),
  getNode: function(callback),
  getWhisper: function(callback)
}

Comment: What does `web3.eth.getCode('0x53BB83974E6dB225449a1Bde977a4B713e5560c1')` give you?

Comment: @goodvibration - I already checked that. It spits out the code and doesn't give me 0x. Truncated to keep it under the character limit - > web3.eth.getCode('0x53BB83974E6dB225449a1Bde977a4B713e5560c1')
"0x608060405234801561001057600080fd5b50600436106100935760003560e01c8063313ce56711610066578063313ce5671461022557806370a082311461024957806395d89b41146102a1578063a9059cbb14610324578063dd62ed3e1461038a57610093565b806306fdde0314610098578063095ea7b31461011b57806318160ddd1461018157806323b872dd1461019

Comment: Can you please `console.log(erc20.address)`?

Comment: > console.log(erc20.address)
0x53BB83974E6dB225449a1Bde977a4B713e5560c1

Comment: And `console.log(erc20.name)`?

Comment: > console.log(erc20.name)
function () { [native code] }

Comment: BTW, what code did you use for deploying the contract?

Comment: https://goethereumbook.org/en/smart-contract-deploy/

Comment: Possibly you just need to change `erc20.name()` to `erc20.name.call()`.

Comment: Yeah, anything to do with executing the name is erroring out - > console.log(erc20.name())
Error: gas required exceeds allowance (8000000) or always failing transaction
    at web3.js:3143:20
    at web3.js:6347:15
    at web3.js:5081:36
    at web3.js:4137:16
    at apply (<native code>)
    at web3.js:4223:16
    at <anonymous>:1:13

> console.log(erc20.name.call())
Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number:
    at L (bignumber.js:3:2876)
    at bignumber.js:3:8435
    at a (bignumber.js:3:389)
    at web3.js:1110:23
    at web3.js:1634:20
    at web3.js:826:16

Comment: What is your private blockchain genesis file? If call fails ussualy it is that you forgot to enable constantinople/petersburg opcodes. Since solc 0.5.x the compiled code  requires new opcodes.

Comment: @Ismael - Thank you. I added the genesys file to the post. Not sure what is missing

Comment: @sat You are missing constantinople/petersnurg opcodes. See here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/70737 how to enable them in your genesis file.

Comment: Your gasLimit is waaaay too small. Set it to be "gasLimit": "0xE0000000", reinit the chain and try again.